# How do I use groovy to create a json array?

Tags: json, groovy

Example (thought of) taken from [groovy ws-lite git hub project.](https://github.com/jwagenleitner/groovy-wslite/blob/master/src/integrationTest/groovy/wslite/rest/RESTClientIntegrationSpec.groovy)

Say I have the following code block to send a RESTful post request:

```
void 'Holiday Service get holidays by country, year and month'() {
   given:
   def client = new RESTClient('http://www.holidaywebservice.com/HolidayService_v2/HolidayService2.asmx')
   when:
   def response = client.post(path: '/GetHolidaysForMonth') {
      type ContentType.JSON
      json files: ['spec_test.txt':[content: "2014-12-12"]]
   }

   then:
   200 == response.statusCode
   'text/xml' == response.contentType
   'Christmas' == response.xml
            .Holiday
            .find { it.HolidayCode.text() == 'CHRISTMAS-ACTUAL'}
            .Descriptor.text()
}
```

Here is what's generated in the request body:

```
{"files":{"spec_test.txt":{"content":"2014-12-12"}}}
```

How can I change the code to generate this json array instead:

```
[{"files":{"spec_test.txt":{"content":"2014-12-12"}}}]
```

Note the following code can do the trick:

```
 def sampleRequest = '[{"files":{"spec_test.txt":{"content":"2014-12-12"}}}]'
 def jsonArray = new JsonSlurper().parseText( sampleRequest )

 void 'Holiday Service get holidays by country, year and month'() {
    given:
    def client = new RESTClient('http://www.holidaywebservice.com/HolidayService_v2/HolidayService2.asmx')

    when:
    def response = client.post(path: '/GetHolidaysForMonth') {
       type ContentType.JSON
       json jsonArray
    }

    then:
    200 == response.statusCode
    'text/xml' == response.contentType
    'Christmas' == response.xml
                .Holiday
                .find { it.HolidayCode.text() == 'CHRISTMAS-ACTUAL'}
                .Descriptor.text()
 }
```

But I want to know if there is another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood well You just need to replace the following line:

```
files: ['spec_test.txt':[content: "2014-12-12"]]
```

with this one:

```
[[files: ['spec_test.txt':[content: "2014-12-12"]]]]
```

It just passed a list instead of map to `json` key, but double square brackets are needed because one pair will be *used* to indicate a *map* and the second one to create a *list*.

Comment: Hi Opal, thanks for your answer. I got the following error:
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: json for class: wslite.rest.ContentBuilder

Comment: This seems to be a different problem. Was it working well before? You made only the changes mentioned in my answer?

Comment: It was working before, and I made the only change in your answer.

Comment: Sorry, but the example You provided seems completely invalid. It mixes request to github with holidaywebservice and sending REST query to service which responds with SAOP. When I try to run it fails with 'Not Found'.

Comment: Sorry it was a mixture of examples that I combined. The original github example takes xml as body, and I changed it to json for the the purpose of this question. But it should still be RESUful call, and the response coming back from the server will be xml I think, but we don't need to validate that.

Comment: But in the example You provided You're not connecting to github but to holidaywebservice. Could please edit the question and provide an example the illustrates clearly what is not working?